# Javascript Regex on Intel Mac. Are patterns and subpattern replacement buggy?

Tags: javascript, regex, macos

I work with BBEdit on an Intel Mac with OS X Lion.
I want to turn `str="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i.j"` into `str=["a","b"]["c","d"]["e,"f"]["g","h"]` using Javascript

I have tried this code:

```
var myArray = str.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g,"["$1","$2"]")
```

I have also tried with:

```
var re = new RegExp("(\w+),(\w+)", "g");
var myArray = str.replace(re,"["$1“,"$2“]" );
```

Both work with BBEdit's own search/replace tool and also with several online regex testers, but I can't get it to work within the script.

I have played around with the code for 2 days now and it seems the problem is interpreting the \w because

```
var myArray2 = str.replace(/\,/g,'\"\]\,\[\"')
```

works just fine to produce `a"],["b"],["c"],["d"],["e"],["f"],["g"],["h"],["i"],["j`

I have tried `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w` but this doesn't work either.
Has anyone experienced similar problems? Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: why do you escape the comma  (\,) in your working example, but not in your broken examples ?

Comment: I don't understand; what does this have to do with OS X? And what's with the funky quotes in the second line of the second chunk? I'm also not convinced regex is the right tool for this job when you could just split and build up the new string.

Comment: You noticed David Chan :-) I've tried so many different alterations, escaping commas was just one of them. It didn't seem to make a diffrence. I just happened to pick that one for the example.

Comment: And to Dave Newton about the funky quotes, the same answer as I gave David Chan. They don't see to make a difference, they do turn funky by themselves though sometimes.

Comment: To Dave Newton again. Thanks for the tip about about split. I'll end up doing that probably. I was just wondering if I could get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, and the solution doesn't involve a regular expression. I'll try to explain why, first. Hear me out.

You're trying to solve your problem using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a regular expression, which implies that you're trying to convert the *string* `'str="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i.j"'` into the 
*string* `'str=["a","b"]["c","d"]["e,"f"]["g","h"]'`.

This is pretty easy, and you were almost there:

```
var original = 'str="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i.j"';
var result = original.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, '["$1","$2"]');
// result === 'str="["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"],["g","h"],i.j"';
```

Notice the mismatch in quotes around the replacement string. Alternatively, you could escape the quotes inside the string; `"[\"$1\",\"$2\"]"`.

---

However, I doubt this is what you're trying to do. I think that instead, you're tyring to turn the *string* `"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i.j"` into an *array of arrays*, which (in array literal notation) would be declared by: `[["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["e,"f"], ["g","h"]]`.

This is not something you can do with a single regular expression. With a regular expression you can only can `replace()` a match, `test()` for a match, or return the `match()`es.

Try this, instead (also [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/4vvfv/)):

```
var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i.j";
var parts = str.split(',');
var num_pairs = Math.floor(parts.length / 2);
var result = [];

for (var i=0; i < num_pairs; i+=1) {
    result.push([parts[i*2], parts[(i*2)+1]]);
}
// result === [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]]
```

Since the number of parts is uneven (`i.j` is the ninth element), you will have to decide whether it should be discarded (as in this example). If not, if change [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), the last array will be `["i.j", undefined]`.

---

By the way: regarding your original solution:

```
str.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, "["$1","$2"]");
```

The reason this doesn't work has nothing to do with `\w`. It's just because it throws a `SyntaxError`. Try it, and look at your JavaScript error console.

This is because you didn't escape the "-qoutes inside the string, but you didn't concatenate either. I.e. you could have done this:

```
str.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, "["+$1+","+$2+"]");
```

Notice the concatenation, using `+`. Now it's a valid string and won't throw a `SyntaxError`. It will, however, throw a `TypeError`, because the variables `$1` and `$2` are `undefined`. The key is to turn it into a full-on string:

```
str.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, '["$1","$2"]');
// or
str.replace(/(\w+),(\w+)/g, "[\"$1\",\"$2\"]");
```

The `replace()` function will replace the $-parts in the string with matches values.

Comment: Thanks PPvG. Nice workaround. You're right about the array of arrays. The  code was just part of the whole, there was more. But your solution is very neat. As to the 9th element (and 10th), it should read i,j. There will always be an even number so Math.floor will do just fine. But I am still left wondering if I'll ever get \w to work.

Comment: @Mike: I don't think the `\w` was your problem. I updated my answer with an explanation. :-)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. As I said I spent 2 days trying dozens of different permutations, including your suggestions above. Your code works in online testers but not in my script.

Comment: Just to let you know, I found a permutation that works:`

initString = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j"
searchItem = new RegExp("(\\w+),(\\w+)", "g");
initString.replace(searchItem, "[\"$1\",\"$2\"]");

Thanks for your help